# How to provide codec registry in quarkus mongodb-panache

Tags: mongodb, quarkus, codec, quarkus-panache

I am trying to store and retrieve JSONArray to mongo db using quarkus-mongodb-panache.

```
import io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.MongoEntity;
import io.quarkus.mongodb.panache.PanacheMongoEntity;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;

@MongoEntity(collection="data")
public class A extends PanacheMongoEntity {
    public LocalDate insertTime;
    public JSONArray data;

    public static void save(A a) {
        persist(a);
    }

    public static A findByDate(LocalDate localDate) {     
        return find("insertTime", localDate).firstResult();
    }
}
```

I am able to store JSONArray to mongodb and not able to retreive it. I am getting below mentioned error on reading mongodb entry.

```
Resulted in: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Unable to set value for property 'data' in A
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PropertyAccessorImpl.setError(PropertyAccessorImpl.java:74)
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PropertyAccessorImpl.set(PropertyAccessorImpl.java:60)
    ... 97 more
Resulted in: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Failed to decode 'A'. Decoding 'data' errored with: Unable to set value for property 'data' in A
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecImpl.decodePropertyModel(PojoCodecImpl.java:225)
    ... 95 more
Resulted in: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Decoding into a 'A' failed with the following exception:

Failed to decode 'A'. Decoding 'data' errored with: Unable to set value for property 'data' in A

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
    at org.bson.codecs.pojo.AutomaticPojoCodec.decode(AutomaticPojoCodec.java:40)
    ... 91 more
Resulted in: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
```

I think this can be solved if i provide mongo-jackson-codec. But how do I register codec in mongodb-panache?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB with Panache uses the automatic pojo codec that is able to automatically convert a POJO to a BSON Object.

If your POJO cannot be converted (in this case due to the JSONArray attribute), you should provide a codec for it, our mongodb client support will automatically register any MongoDB codec found, see [Simplifying MongoDB Client usage using BSON codec](https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#simplifying-mongodb-client-usage-using-bson-codec)

Here, I think you need to register a condec to handle the JSONArray type.

**UPDATED** : as the codec is in an external library, this external library needs to be indexed by Jandex for the codec to be discovered by the MongoDB with Panache extension.

To be able to index an external library, you can use the following properties inside your application.properties file:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.mongo-jackson-codec.group-id=fr.javatic.mongo
quarkus.index-dependency.mongo-jackson-codec.artifact-id=mongo-jackson-codec
```

For more information on how to index a dependency, see [How to generate a Jandex index](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#how-to-generate-a-jandex-index) in the CDI reference guide.

Comment: So if I include mongo-jackson-codec library in maven quarkus will automatically register this codec?

Comment: No, there is no Jackson codec for MongoDB provided by Quarkus.
If you want to use arbitrary JSON with MongoDB, you need to provide your own codec. The codec will be automatically registered thanks to the quarkus-mongodb-client extension.

Comment: If i add fr.javatic.mongo:mongo-jackson-codec maven library it is not getting registered automatically.

Comment: @subham ah non the codec must be in your project not on an external dependency or it will not be discovered by the extension.
I'll make an answer later to explain how to workaround this.

Comment: @subham I updated the answer to explain how to create a Jandex index for an external dependency. If you index the fr.javatic.mongo:mongo-jackson-codec, the codec should be discovered and automatically registered.